# Unable To Access EOS

Tags: tokens

I'm really hoping someone can help me. I'm struggling to access my EOS since the main-net launch (yes I know this was a while ago).

I registered my EOS tokens prior to the cut-off date and held them using my Ledger Nano S but it wasn't until recently that I have tried to access my EOS using the private key that I was provided upon registering my tokens. I can view my EOS with the public address that I was provided and it is all still sitting there but when I try to use my private key, I am told "unrecognised private key type". It is 100% correct as I checked numerous times when I took it down.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if you could point e in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your private key follow this format? Here's a sample keypair I have just generated: Private key: 5HzYitmMbjnDy9eWSjYpr4XpTQius6AHnEKRkfRK8QWey1Q7SLf
Public key: EOS6qYiVZKHeGxGrbY5P6aS8JPPupb1mrd2QYze6WR5Kq2b5zk3op -- note that all private keys start with a "5", and it seems the first two letters are always "5H", "5J" or "5K", at least that's what I see here if I try to generate a bunch of keys. Also, try downloading Scatter (get-scatter.com) and entering your private key manually there. (DON'T POST your private key here, of course)

Comment: Yes the private key and public address both start with the correct format. I'll give it a go. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Tried Scatter with no luck. Am I just typing the private key into the first screen where it asks for a password?
Also, your example private key has 51 characters, SimplEOS only allows for 50 characters (I have 50 characters in mine, not 51 as well).

Comment: The first screen in Scatter is the wallet password.

Comment: I have generated a bunch of private keys here (20+) using ```cleos create key --to-console``` and all of them have 51 characters total. You probably forgot a letter somewhere. If that's the case, the good news is that writing some software/tool to find the missing letter is not very difficult and it should complete pretty quickly.

Comment: Here's a Github issue from May 2018 showing that private keys always had 51 chars: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/2749

Comment: In case you need it, I wrote a modified version of the ```cleos``` wallet that knows how to fix a couple of typos and/or missing characters in a written-down private key: https://github.com/fcecin/cleos_key_fixer/